# serverless lambda function with dynamodb connect issue

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless

I'm using serverless framework to code AWS lambda function. I need to get a form data from a HTML page and save it to Dynamodb using AWS lambda. So i have written the code in nodejs and API endpoints as well. Finally i deployed the application to AWS. So when i'm trying to post data using both CURL and Postman, it shows an "Internal Server Error"

Following are the relevant code snippets.

handler.js

```js
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      name: data.name,
      phone: data.phone,
      checked: false,
      createdAt: timestamp,
      updatedAt: timestamp,
    },
  };
```

serverless.yml

```js
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"
```

I'm not sure where to define the Dynamo table name and whether it is created by while running the code by automatically? And i followed this github repo - https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb

Comment: What's the error that shows up on CloudWatch?

Comment: The error is probably because you haven't created the DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `serverless.yml` does not define and create the DynamoDB table for you.

You can do it by defining it in the `resources` section of your `serverless` config.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-phones
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:*


resources:
  Resources:
    phonesTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-phones
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Reference: 
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/

Comment: So you have defined phonesTable. Is this the table which i should create in the dynamodb? Is this a specific format? I created as formdata_table

Comment: And what this means Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:*? I have defined this as "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

Comment: Mine means any DynamoDB table that your account owns. You can be more specific like what you use if that works for you. In most cases, you don't have to be that specific.

Comment: That means it's creating the database on the fly?

Comment: This table is created on your next `sls deploy`. On your succeeding deploys, `serverless` will know that you didn't change anything so it won't be recreated.